# no element or plugin 'alsasrc'

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

[System Info:]

- Ubuntu 16.04 in a Virtualbox
- Kernel: Linux 4.13.0-36-generic
- Architecture: x86-64
- ROS kinetic

I am trying to set up the audio pipeline with audio_common following the steps in this tutorial.

http://wiki.ros.org/audio_common/Tutorials/Streaming%20audio

When I try to test the audio pipeline with

```
gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "alsasrc".
```

During the audio-common download I recognised that gstreamer version 1.0 was installed (not 0.10), but the command above gives the same error, even with gst-launch-1.0.

Does someone have an idea how to solve this and make the pipeline work?
Any comment would be appreciated!

Best
Nina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286550/no-element-or-plugin-%27alsasrc%27/) by [nina-lg](https://answers.ros.org/users/34315/nina-lg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-26**:
Is [arrdem/Voicely#1](https://github.com/arrdem/Voicely/issues/1) similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kind of. But I already had all plugins installed.
I now installed
`sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-alsa`
and it seemed that the pipeline was setup properly. But still i cannot hear my microphone input through the headphones...

---

Originally posted by [nina-lg](https://answers.ros.org/users/34315/nina-lg/) with karma: 76 on 2018-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-26**:
That would be a different (ie: new) problem then.

**Comment by [nina-lg](https://answers.ros.org/users/34315/nina-lg/) on 2018-03-26**:
Exactly.. that's why I opened this one.
https://answers.ros.org/question/286566/cannot-initialise-gstreamer-pipeline/